# Matlabcontrol: isExistingSession vs. setUsePreviouslyControlledSession

Tags: java, matlab, session, proxy, matlabcontrol

I've made a web service using Java 7 and Matlabcontrol-4.1.0. In this web service, i'm starting a Matlab r2015a session to execute a function. As far as I can see, isExistingSession and setUsePreviouslyControlledSession are functions to use a previously created session.

Q: In order to get the best performance, which method should I use?

isExistingSession (MatlabProxy) and/or setUsePreviouslyControlledSession (MatlabProxyFactoryOptions)?

I am using the following code at the moment:

```
    // setting up connection to MatLab
    MatlabProxyFactoryOptions options = new MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder()
            .setUsePreviouslyControlledSession(true).setHidden(true)
            .setMatlabLocation(null).build();

    MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory(options);
    MatlabProxy proxy = factory.getProxy();
```

I have checked [setUsePreviouslyControlledSession](http://matlabcontrol.googlecode.com/svn/javadocs/doc/matlabcontrol/MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder.html#setUsePreviouslyControlledSession(boolean)) and [isExistingSession](http://matlabcontrol.googlecode.com/svn/javadocs/doc/matlabcontrol/MatlabProxy.html#isExistingSession()), but I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging in the documentation, I think i've looked at it the wrong way.

- setUsePreviouslyControlledSession (MatlabProxyFactoryOptions): sets whether to use a previously started session.
- isExistingSession (MatlabProxy): Just returns a boolean answering "is there already a session running?".

These methods have different functions, so the comparison was never valid.